# How to install perl-tk to run Texdoctk on macOS 11.2.3

Tags: mac, perl, texdoc

I'm attempting to run texdoctk on my Mac but I've encountered the following error:

```
The program texdoctk needs the package perl-tk, please install it!
```

I've reinstalled [MacTeX 2021](https://tug.org/mactex/) and attempted to install perl-tk through [CPAN](https://www.cpan.org/) with very little success. I'd also restarted my Mac as well.

I've also reached out to my colleagues who are experienced in TeX and haven't been able to help me.

Comment: Unfortunately, texdoctk is unmaintained for a long time. I would rather recommend you to directly use texdoc, the command-line tool, or texdoc.org for Web-based GUI (though the latter requires network access).

Answer (score 1):

I did find a solution to this error which involved installing XQuartz[1](https://www.xquartz.org) on to my mac which appeared to have fixed the issue.